# Epimorphism of Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

For a $k$-algebra $R$, let $Mod R$ denote the category of all left $R$-modules. Furthermore, by $mod R$ we denote the full subcategory of $Mod R$ which consists of all finitely generated left $R$-modules.

For two $k$-algebras $A$ and $B$, it seems to be a well-known fact that $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism of algebras if and only if the corresponding forgetful functor $Mod B \rightarrow Mod A$ is full.

I have two questions about this fact:

1. I could not find an easy reference for that. I would be thankful for such information.
2. In the above equivalence, can one replace the module categories $Mod A$ and $Mod B$, respectively by $mod A$ and $mod B$? If not, a concrete non-example would be appreciated.

Comment: The forgetful functor does not preserve the property of being finitely generated, but that is basically the only problem. The property of being full or not is determined by the restriction to the subcategory of finitely presented modules.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for the quick response. 
Do you have a counterexample in mind, when the forgetful functor sends a module in $mod B$ to an infinitely generated module in $Mod A$?

Comment: Take $B$ itself. It is not always finitely generated as an $A$-module.

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by epimorphism? A surjective homomorphism of rings, or an epimorphism (in the sense of category theory!) in the category of rings?

Comment: I meant epimorphism in the sense of category theory. Namely, I also consider the morphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ as an epimorphism. And I think this particular epimorphism would work as a non-example.